# Partial decimate?

Tags: vertices

I know that there's the **Decimate** modifier for reducing polygons on models, is there a similar modifier which you can use **only on areas where there are polygons smaller than some area "X"**?

I have some models where most of the model looks ok, but there are small areas with unnecessarily high concentration of triangles that I want to simplify. They're very hard to manually select via Box/Circle select due to overlapping with other parts of the object.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, might want to try the Remesh Modifier instead: http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using either **Dissolve Faces** or **Limited Dissolve** options.

#### Dissolving faces

First you should select what you'd like to get rid of.

Select those tiny polygons (select one of them, and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Area* to select them by area)

[image]

Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Faces* and choose option *Dissolve Vertices* in operator menu (<kbd>F6</kbd>). This makes all those unneeded vertices along the edges to be dissolved too as they will remain by default.

[image]

Beware though that this way is a little bit incomplete meaning that it doesn't accurately provide you with original topology as it was before. Weird Ngons will remain in places where dissolved geometry was before. It's possible though to use **Mesh** > *Clean-Up* > *Split Concave faces*, or use triangulating (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), but this may be undesirable.

#### Limited Dissolve

When using this feature you can either select only small polygons like written above or it's possible just to select all with <kbd>A</kbd>
and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. It's possible to setup limit angle in the operator panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>).

[image]

---

There is also option of retopologizing which is completely another approach (so not to *delete* polygons of exhisting model, rather than *recreate* new ones atop of them). It's described also on this site, and basically includes using either [**Shrinkwrap**](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html?highlight=shrinkwrap) or [**Remesh**](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html#remesh-modifier) modifiers.

Read more:

[Merging, deleting and dissolving in wiki](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html?highlight=dissolve#dissolve).

[Mesh-Cleanup in wiki](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/cleanup.html?highlight=dissolve#mesh-clean-up).